# How do I change the dataframe column values given certain condition(s)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the below table I am trying to change the figures in the column "Value" if it meets the condition.

Condition: if the "Date" for Identifier A_xcxcxcis < '05/05/2021' then "Value" for both A_xcxcxc and DAB_bcbcbc (the row below it) is changed to zero, else both values remain the same (the two rows are linked to each other).

Then it will perform the same check for BAB_bnbnb, CCC_eetr, D_tyty, and so on. I have shown the expected answer to the table below.

*** Had to make some edits to the original table

New table:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'IDENTIFIER': ['A_xcxcxc', 'DAB_bcbcbc', 'BAB_bnbnb', 'XYZ_ererte', 'CCC_eetr', 'CZc_rgrg', 'D_tyty', 'sdD_wewerw', 'sdE_tyty', 'Esd_fhg'], 
                   'income': [-30362100.0, 200000.0, -21248077.5, 150000.0, -33843389.2, 200000.0, -40229279.75, 250000.0, -22111384.6, 200000.0],
'Date' : ['03/03/2021', '22/01/2060', '04/03/2021', '22/07/2068', '08/03/2021', '22/11/2065', '05/04/2021', '22/03/2052', '15/10/2025', '22/07/2065']
})
```

[image]

Expected answer:

[image]

Comment: Do not provide your data as a picture, we cannot copy and use it.

Comment: yeh, have been trying to fix that past 10 mins. everytime I paste from my excel it goes in as picture

Comment: Here's a good guide [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), basically just use `pd.DataFrame..` so we can copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
         .groupby(df['IDENTIFIER'].str.split('_').str[0])
         .transform('first')
         .lt(pd.to_datetime('05/05/2021', format='%d/%m/%Y')), 'income'] = 0
print(df)

  IDENTIFIER      income        Date
0   A_xcxcxc         0.0  03/03/2021
1   A_bcbcbc         0.0  22/01/2060
2    B_bnbnb         0.0  04/03/2021
3   B_ererte         0.0  22/07/2068
4     C_eetr         0.0  08/03/2021
5     C_rgrg         0.0  22/11/2065
6     D_tyty         0.0  05/04/2021
7   D_wewerw         0.0  22/03/2052
8     E_tyty -22111384.6  15/10/2025
9      E_fhg    200000.0  22/07/2065
```

If you want groupby each two rows:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
         .groupby(np.arange(df.shape[0])//2)
         .transform('first')
         .lt(pd.to_datetime('05/05/2021', format='%d/%m/%Y')), 'income'] = 0
print(df)
```

Comment: thanks @ansev, that worked well just going through my file and there are over 1000 rows. some of the "row - pairs" dont have the same first alphabet. so if you replace your row 1 Identifier with something else say DFT_xxxtd your solution would work. am amending the original question as well.

Comment: ok, so now the problem comes down to finding an object to use with GroupBy :)

Comment: i have changed the orignal table now in the question.

Comment: I think @ansev already assume this fact and had written the code accordingly.

Comment: no, it doesnt give me the answer when I change the names under Identifier